# Github - How to pull back 2 files from PR

Tags: github, pull-request

I changed 2 files (A and B) and 2 others (C and D) were generated by webpack by itself.

Now committed by mistake all 4 files (instead of only A and B) to my new branch `Branch2` and created PR against branch `Branch1`.

How to un-commit (revert to yesterday's state) files C and D from `Branch2` and from PR as well? (PR is not approved/merged yet).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the commit hash before your commit, using `git log`
2. On the branch you made, check out the old files using the commit hash you obtained in step 1:

   ```
   git checkout Id07dd67b412d56f64e05246ea0b87924f8a803cb path/to/file
   ```
3. Add & Commit
4. Push your new commit

Comment: Awesome! This worked exactly perfect! Love the ability to point to individual file and commit previous version of it.. Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`git reset` to the commit before you change A and B, then commit them again, `git push -f` to remote